# Como vincular duas contas no WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Como fazer isso no WooCommerce?

Cadastrar um cliente vinculado à conta do representante, aí tudo que o cliente comprar o representante poderá ver. E com isso a empresa pagará uma comissão ao representante.

Assim o representante saberá tudo que o cliente está comprando para ele receber sua comissão.

Existe alguma maneira de ter esse controle?

Answer (score 1):

Vai ser necessário implementar diversas funcionalidades para montar esse sistema. E o começo é exatamente "vincular contas de usuários".

Clientes e representantes terão um papel ([*role*](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Pap%C3%A9is_e_Capacidades)) separado, isso pode ser gerenciado manualmente via código ou usando um [plugin especializado](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). Vou mostrar aqui como fazer isso na página de Perfil dos usuários. O cliente pode escolher seu representante, e o representante pode ver quais clientes estão associados a ele. A lógica disso pode ser diferente e a interface pode ser implementada no *frontend* junto com os formulários do WooCommerce, mas as funções para consultar/gravar dados de usuário serão as mesmas (consultar Codex para definições):

- `get_users()`
- `get_user_meta()`
- `update_user_meta()`
- `current_user_can()`
- `current_user_has_role()` - esta é uma função personalizada criada por mim a partir de referências

Neste exemplo, uso os papéis padrão, sendo *Subscriber* equivalente a *Cliente*, e *Author* equivalente a *Representante*. Aqui estou usando programação procedural, mas é melhor [OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A201%20%5Bwordpress%5D%20get_instance) (nesses exemplos linkados, vai ver como fazer o cabeçalho de um plugin, que é como deve implementar o código abaixo).

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_70265_init');

/**
 * Novos campos no perfil de clientes e representantes
 */
function wpse_70265_init() 
{
    if( current_user_has_role( 'author' ) ) 
    {
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'mostrar_cliente_sopt_39058', 10 );    
    }
    if( current_user_has_role( 'administrator' ) ||  current_user_has_role( 'subscriber' ) )
    {
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'mostrar_representante_sopt_39058', 10 );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'mostrar_representante_sopt_39058', 10 );
        add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'guardar_representante_sopt_39058' );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'guardar_representante_sopt_39058' );
    } 
}

/**
 * Mostra lista de clientes no perfil do representante
 */
function mostrar_cliente_sopt_39058( $user ) 
{
    ?> 
    <h2>Clientes</h2>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="agree">Nome</label></th>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $users = get_users( array( 'role' => 'subscriber', 'meta_key' => 'representante', 'meta_value' => $user->ID ) );
                    foreach( $users as $user )
                    {
                        printf(
                            '<li>%s</li>',
                            $user->data->user_nicename
                        );
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </td>           
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Mostra lista de representantes no perfil dos clientes
 */
function mostrar_representante_sopt_39058( $user ) 
{
    ?> 
    <h2>Representante</h2>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="agree">Selecionar</label></th>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $users = get_users( array( 'role' => 'author' ) );
                    $saved =  get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'representante', true );
                    foreach( $users as $user )
                    {
                        printf(
                            '<li><label><input type="radio" name="representante" value="%1$s" id="representante[%1$s]" %3$s />'.
                            ' %2$s ' .
                            '</label></li>',
                            esc_attr( $user->ID ),
                            esc_html( $user->data->user_nicename ),
                            checked( $saved, $user->ID, false )
                        );
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </td>           
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Grava o representante escolhido pelo administrador ou cliente
 */
function guardar_representante_sopt_39058( $user_id ) 
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'representante', $_POST['representante'] );
}

/**
 * Function name grabbed from: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624
 * 2 lines of code from TutPlus: http://goo.gl/X4lmf
 */
if( !function_exists( 'current_user_has_role' ) )
{
    function current_user_has_role( $role )
    {
        $current_user = new WP_User( wp_get_current_user()->ID );
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $is_or_not = in_array( $role, $user_roles );
        return $is_or_not;
    }
}
```